# What is the actual successor of Samsung's PM961 SSD family?

Tags: ssd

I have an SSD from Samsung from PM961 family. It is quite outdated, but I couldn't really find the current alternative for replacement.

All I found is PM981 was its successor, but it is also outdated for now.

Can you help me tracking the family path?

Comment: Being (I think) a server class SSD I wonder uf its more appropriate on Serverfault?  Also, do yoy need SATA or M2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSD SM961 and PM961 are only sold to PC manufacturers,
not to to the public. They are the OEM versions of the
Samsung 960 PRO and EVO.

In general, the "family" of the SSD is of no importance - any SSD
that has the same
specifications as your actual one will work : M.2, PCIe x4, NVMe.
It doesn't even have to be from Samsung.

If you are unsure, buy from a vendor that has a good return policy
(always good to do).

Comment: In case of Samsung 980 PRO: it is PCIe gen 4, but should it be backward compatible with gen3 PCIe? (based on topics on internet it should, but nowadays everything seems unreliable source of info)

Comment: A gen 4 SSD usually work with a gen 3 motherboard if it is downward compatible. Most are, but will only run at the speed limitations of the controller. See the specs to be sure.